# github says cannot parse json while creating a repo in rest api

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, github-api

I'm learning REST api for github and trying to create a new repository by running a JS. Here is my function for creating a new repo: the token is generated, and all access/scopes is granted for my token.

```
function createNewRepo(userId, name){

    var options = {
        url: urlRoot + "/user/repos",
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "EnableIssues",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": token,
            "name": name,
            "description": "This is repo creating by REST",
            "homepage": "https://github.com",
            "private": false,
            "has_issues": true,
            "has_projects": true,
            "has_wiki": true,

        }
    };
    //console.log(eval(options));


    request(options, function (error, response, body) 
    {
        var obj = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log( obj );
    });

}
```

however when running this, I find,

```
{ message: 'Problems parsing JSON', documentation_url: 'https://developer.github.com/v3' }
```

I'm not sure how exactly could the JSON be invalid.

Also, the documentation says it must include `public_repo` or `repo` which I'm also not sure how to apply here.

Comment: What json? You neglect to include the json you're sending.

Comment: I'm really not sure. I'm new to javascript. I thought the options are being sent to github as json object. Whatever the case, the message returns "problem parsing json" while running this function ! @DaveNewton

Comment: They are, but you've put everything into the headers, and nothing in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for me has created the repository.

```
var myToken = "token INSERTHERETHETOKEN"; // <-- there must be the word token before the actual token.
var urlRoot = "https://api.github.com";
var request = require("request");

function createNewRepo(user, name, token){
  var options = {
    url: urlRoot + "/user/repos",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": user,
      // "content-type": "application/json", This is set by json:true
      "Authorization": token,
      "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
    },
    body: { 
      "name": name,
      "description": "This is repo creating by REST",
      "homepage": "https://github.com",
      "private": false,
      "has_issues": true,
      "has_projects": true,
      "has_wiki": true
    },
    json: true 
  };

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    // Do your stuff... but notice that response
    // is already a json object and you don't need to parse it.
  });
}

createNewRepo("YourGithubUser", "test.repository", myToken);
```

Comment: this time it gives:
undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Request._callback,..............

Comment: I've tested the code. The error is raised by the line of `JSON.parse`, in your callback.

Comment: oh thank you very much. I don't have much experience working with json object. pardon my ignorance !

Comment: Yes: response is ALREADY a js object, so you don't need to parse it, and if you try it fails.

Comment: Don't worry, asking questions is why SE exists. Glad that it helped you